# set of functions $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int_a^b f(x) dx=1$, a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U$ be the set of all continuous functions $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx=1$.

With the usual operations of pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, is $U$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

My first thought is no, because:

Let $a=0$ and $b=1$.
Let $f(x)=1$.
Take $\int_a^b [f(x)+f(x)] dx=2$.
Then, this is not closed under addition.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Almost correct. Who said that the constant function $f(x)\equiv 1$ lies in $U$?

Comment: Also, $\,\int_a^b2f\,dx=2\,$...

Comment: Re to edit: ok with $a=0, b=1$ but what about the general case? You can follow DonAntonio advice above.

Answer (score 2):

"With the usual operations of pointwise addition and scalar multiplication..." These are not operations on the set $U$, as you noticed.  Far from it: for all $f,g\in U$, $f+g\not\in U$, and for all $f\in U$, $\lambda\in\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}$, $\lambda f\not\in U$.  (There is also no additive identity, but that is a little strange to consider when there is no addition in the first place.)

One concrete example suffices as in your solution, but technically the example should apply to the general $[a,b]$, not just to $[0,1]$.  You could adapt your example slightly to accommodate the general case.